# How to use non-pooling virtual threads to execute asynchronous tasks in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, threadpool, java-21, virtual-threads

Java 21 has officially supported the feature of virtual threads, and I am very excited to use this feature in Spring Boot

I've come across a statement: "We should not treat virtual threads the same way as platform threads by using pools to constrain them because they are very lightweight resources that can be discarded once they are used up."

Is there any other way to make Spring Boot's @Async annotation use virtual threads to handle asynchronous tasks without needing to register a virtual thread pool like the following?

```java
@EnableAsync
@Configuration
public class AsyncThreadConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public AsyncTaskExecutor asyncTaskExecutor() {
        return new TaskExecutorAdapter(Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor());
    }

    @Bean
    public TomcatProtocolHandlerCustomizer<?> protocolHandlerVirtualThreadExecutorCustomizer() {
        return protocolHandler -> protocolHandler.setExecutor(Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor());
    }
}
```

I look forward to a simple configuration approach that allows the @Async annotation to use virtual threads to execute asynchronous tasks without the need for a thread pool.

Comment: As far as I can see, there is no pool in your example, as you’re using a `TaskExecutorAdapter` wrapping a `newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor()`. You’re not using a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` or such alike. In other words, it looks do me as if you already solved your task.

Comment: So, the `newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor` is not a traditional thread pool, is that correct?

Comment: Exactly. As the name suggests and [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor()) says, it creates a new virtual thread for every task.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. By the way, do you think this virtual thread approach provides a significant performance boost for handling high-concurrency asynchronous tasks?

Comment: This heavily depends on your starting point. Depending on how you handled concurrency before, they may not add to performance but allow you to write far more maintainable code *or* allow higher concurrency and in turn, higher performance. But it may require replacing some older “best practice” code by new “best practice” code in your application. There’s no general statement possible.

Comment: You could also wait until Spring Boot 3.2 releases in November with full virtual thread support and set `spring.threads.virtual.enabled=true` in your `application.properties`